# Is there a way to determine whether an ActiveJob is being performed on a Resque worker or within the application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, rails-activejob, resque-scheduler

I have an Job in my rails app that extends from ActiveJob::Base, and there are two ways that it is called:

1. ResqueScheduler on a daily basis, where it is picked up by a Resque worker and processed
2. Within the app via a #perform_now call, so it is processed by the app.

Is there a way for me to determine within the job whether it is being processed by a Resque worker?

Answer (score 0):

You should see a reference to `ActiveJob` in your server log.

```
[ActiveJob] [<YOUR-JOB-CLASS>] [b8ed2ecb-10ce-433d-8ddb-33a04c8021cd]    Performing <YOUR-JOB-CLASS> from Resque(default)...
```

This isn't definitive but it's a strong indicator in to the context your code is being executed.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out during the code execution - I'm record certain information if the job is being performed in the background, but not if #perform_now is called.

Comment: Best solution I've found so far is basically overriding the perform_now method to add a variable to the arguments, but I was hoping there was a better way.

Answer (score -2):

You could use `defined?(Rails)` to determine if you are inside the Rails app or if you are in the Resque context.